# Computing marginal distribution from two independent normally distributed random variables

Tags: statistics, marginal-distribution

## Problem

Given two independent random variables$Z_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Z_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, what are the marginal distributions for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ in all three cases?

(1) $Y_1 = Z_1 + 2$, $Y_2 = 3Z_1 + 3Z_2$

(2) $Y_1 = Z_1 + 2$, $Y_2 = 3\sqrt{2}Z_2$

(3) $Y_1 = Z_1 + 2$, $Y_2 = 3\sqrt{2}Z_1$

## Context and Attempt

This is not a homework problem, just a question asked in a slide deck. Referring to case (1), it seems like these functions can be re-written to $f_{Z_1}(z_1) = z_1 + 2$ and $f_{Z_1, Z_2}(z_1, z_2) = 3 z_1 + 3 z_2$ (per the notation in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48304/how-to-find-marginal-distribution-from-joint-distribution-with-multi-variable-de) question). Since from the [marginal distribution wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution), it seems like the joint distribution must be known, and then the marginal distribution can be obtained by integrating the joint probability distribution as shown below:

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{Z_1}(z_1) &= \int_c^d f(z_1, z_2)\ dz_2, \\
f_{Z_2}(z_2) &= \int_a^b f(z_1, z_2)\ dz_1. 
\end{aligned}
$$

So it seems like a possible solution, at least for case (1) is to perform the following integrals

$$
\begin{aligned}
f_{Z_1}(z_1) &= \int_0^1 3z_1 + 3z_2\ dz_2 = \left[3 z_1 z_2 + \frac{3 z_2^2}{2} \right]_0^1 = 3 z_1 + \frac{3}{2}, \\
f_{Z_2}(z_2) &= \int_0^1 3z_1 + 3z_2\ dz_1 = \frac{3}{2} + 3 z_2, 
\end{aligned}
$$

however, this doesn't really seem correct in the context of the given problem, even though it generally aligns with the websites I have linked. Moreover, for case (2) and (3) there is no joint probability distribution function provided, so I wouldn't even know how to proceed.

Comment: All of the are normal and you only have to compute their means and variances. This does not require any integration.

Comment: So would it just be sufficient to compute for each case $\mathbb{E}[Y_1], \mathbb{E}[Y_2]$ and $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[Y_1], \mathbb{V}\text{ar}[Y_2]$?

Comment: That is it. No need for joint pdf's and integration.

Comment: Integration would still be needed for $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[Y_i]$ though, right? Because while the second term in $\mathbb{V}\text{ar}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2$ is just the square of the expectation, the first term (as an example) for $\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2] = \int_0^1 (z_1 + 2)(z_1 + 2)\ \rho(z_1)\ dz_1 = \int_0^1 z_1^2 + 4 z_1 + 4\ \rho(z_1) \ dz_1$, where $\rho(z_1)$ is the pdf for the normal distribution.

Comment: No. $Var (X+a)=Var (X)$, $Var (cX)=c^{2}Var (X)$,  and $Var (X+Y)=Var(X)+Var (Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Oh right, because we know the random variables are normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2 = 1$, as an example for case (1) therefore $Var[Y_1] = Var[Z_1] + 2 = 1 + 2 = 3$. Similarly, for case (1) $Var[Y_2]  = Var[3 Z_1] + Var[3 Z_2] = 9 Var[Z_1] + 9 Var[Z_2] = 18$.